# Invoke public lambda from a VPC lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to invoke a lambda function from another lambda function:

```
boto3.client('lambda').invoke(
    FunctionName = 'arn:aws:...',
    nvocationType = 'RequestResponse',
    Payload = json.dumps(inputParams)
)
```

The parent lambda is in a vpc, whereas the child lambda is public

But it does not work. I don't want to use NAT gateways.

This is what I configured to make it work:

- I created a new endpoint with `com.amazonaws.<region>.lambda` for my vpc and all of its subnets
- I added a security group with outbounds rules of type https and destination of   0.0.0.0/0
- I added my parent lambda to the same vpc, subnets and security group
- My vpc has DNS and also the endpoint has private dns names enabled
- I added to my parent lambda the following permission policies:

  ```
  {
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": [
               "lambda:InvokeFunction"
           ],
           "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<account-id>:function:<child-function-name>"
       }
   ]
  ```

  }

Both functions work independently. The problem starts when I try to invoke from my parent. I cant figure out how to solve this issue. Whenever my parent lambda tries to invoke my child lambda it just keeps hanging until the parent timed out.

Comment: What security group did you assign to the VPC endpoint? Specifically, what **inbound** rules are in the security group assigned to the VPC endpoint?